# postgresql list all table fields information within a server

Tags: sql, postgresql, metadata

i'm in need to create VIEWS in postresql 9, to mimic oracle's `col` table, 
basically it should display ALL table fields information from ALL table and ALL database on that server.

Can someone please point me a way? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Oracle, PostgreSQL implements the ANSI information_schema.

So Oracle's `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` view corresponds to `information_schema.columns`

But this is only restricted to the current database. It is not possible to get this information for all databases - which is the same for Oracle, `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` only shows the columns for the current database (=instance)

More details about the information_schema can be found in the manual

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible to get metadata information from a different database of that you've working right now.
To extract metadata from the current database, take a look here: http://www.alberton.info/postgresql_meta_info.html